# Is There a Breaking Change to the Ember.CollectionView API in the Latest Build?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have two examples with the same CollectionView code running under 9.8.1 and latest.The 9.8.1 version works: http://jsfiddle.net/ethan_selzer/kcjzw/230/. But the latest version does not: http://jsfiddle.net/kcjzw/232/.

Are there breaking-changes to the Ember.CollectionView API in the latest build? Or, is there an issue with the current build of the CollectionView?

Thanks,
Ethan

Comment: I think you should ask a [question](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues?labels=question&page=1&state=open) directly in the repository issue list and get answers from the developers.

Comment: Thanks MilkyWayJoe. I submitted the question in the Ember repo as you suggested.

Comment: Kristofor Selden responded to this question on the official repository issue tracker. Here is his guidance: The default context has changed from the view to the controller. you can change the context via a binding like so http://jsfiddle.net/krisselden/6fAHZ/

Comment: Can you post the link to your question here, or add an answer with the question you asked them?

Comment: Here is [this question](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/1152) on the official repo. Thanks MilkyWayJoe for pointing out my omission and for your original suggestion!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can either do what Kristofor Selden suggested in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krisselden/6fAHZ/ (bind the `content` array in the `itemViewClass`) or you can do it as follows:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/ppanagi/WhGjR/

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.collectionView = Ember.CollectionView.create({

    content: [
      { key: 'value one' },
      { key: 'value two' }
    ],

    itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
      template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{view.content.key}}')
    })
});

App.collectionView.append();​
```

The default context of templates are now controller variables, so `{{foo}}` will return the value of the controller variable `foo`. If you need the value of `bar` variable of the View, use `{{view.bar}}`.

---

Follow up: Yet another way to change the context is to use `{{with}}`:

```
App.collectionView = Ember.CollectionView.create({
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile('{{#with view}} {{content.key}} {{/with}}')
});
```

Comment: Thanks Zack. Definitely a valuable contribution.